How to find part of a subject line in outlook vba
We have a shared ticketing system where employees will submit requests that generate an email with a subject line such as "Review Ticket - Ticket: TI-0000145176" All of these record IDs are formatted identically with the same number of digits. If another member of my team gets to the ticket before I do, I will get an email with the subject "Automatic Approval - Ticket: TI-0000145176"
I'm trying to write a script that will look for the corresponding "review ticket" email when the "automatic approval" email comes in and delete both emails so that I am not wasting my time clicking into the system to review a ticket that has already been processed. No, I can't change the email settings on the ticketing system.
This question helped me get started, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse out the ticket ID from the subject line.
Any help would be very appreciated, as this is hundreds of emails a week for us!
Update:
I'm 99% sure I have this working now. I'm sure there is a better way to do some of this, but it is working for me now. I left in some logging so that I can manually check deleted tickets to make sure this is working as intended.
Sub Delete_approved_expense_reports()

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim filteredItems As Outlook.Items
Dim filteredItems2 As Outlook.Items
Dim reportNumbers As String
Dim reportNumbers2 As String
Dim itm As Object
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim strFilter As String
Dim strFilter2 As String


Set objNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%Automatic Approval - Ticket: TI-0000%'"
strFilter2 = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%Review Ticket - Ticket: TI-%'"

Set filteredItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
Set filteredItems2 = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter2)


If filteredItems.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails found"
    Found = False
Else
    Found = True
    For Each itm In filteredItems
     'There is sometimes some extra junk at the end of the subject line that needs to be accounted for
     reportNumbers = Left(Mid(itm.Subject, InStr(1, itm.Subject, "TI-0000", 1)), 13)
     For Each jtm In filteredItems2
      reportNumbers2 = Mid(jtm.Subject, Len(jtm.Subject) - 12)
      If reportNumbers2 = reportNumbers Then
       jtm.Delete
      'List the expense reports that are deleted as resolved
       Debug.Print reportNumbers2
      End If
     itm.Delete
     Next
      
    
    Next
End If


'If the subject isn't found:
If Not Found Then
    'NoResults.Show
Else
   Debug.Print "Found " & filteredItems.Count & " items."

End If

'myOlApp.Quit
Set myOlApp = Nothing

End Sub


Please share the details of the code you tried and describe the issue you are encountering.

If the ticket ID is always the last 13 characters, you could do this Mid(ticket, Len(ticket) - 12)

Thanks Brian, that definitely clicked something in my brain and helped me understand what I was doing wrong! I have it working now with Left(Mid(itm.Subject, InStr(1, itm.Subject, "TI-0000", 1)), 13)
